# ibpy: extract API responses for multiple contracts

Tags: python, tws, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am interested in using ibpy with Interactive Brokers API to get real time tick data for a given universe of 100 stocks.  The code below, from examples on the web works for one stock.  Can someone tell me how i can do this for 100 stocks at the same time?

Python script:

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from time import sleep

def my_callback_handler(msg):
    inside_mkt_bid = ''
    inside_mkt_ask = ''

    if msg.field == 1:
        inside_mkt_bid = msg.price
        print 'bid', inside_mkt_bid
    elif msg.field == 2:
        inside_mkt_ask = msg.price
        print 'ask', inside_mkt_ask


tws = ibConnection()
tws.register(my_callback_handler, message.tickSize, message.tickPrice)
tws.connect()

c = Contract()
c.m_symbol = "DATA"
c.m_secType = "STK"
c.m_exchange = "SMART"
c.m_currency = "USD"

tws.reqMktData(1,c,"",False)
sleep(25)

print 'All done'

tws.disconnect()
```

Command line output:

```
    Server Version: 76
    TWS Time at connection:20150508 13:42:02 EST
    bid 111.42
    ask 111.5
    bid 111.43
    bid 111.44
    bid 111.42
    bid 111.38
    bid 111.32
    ask 111.44
    All done
```

Answer (score 10):

When you request data, you give a tickerId that identifies which request the response message is for.

I would read a list of securities from a file and put them in a data frame and just use the index as the tickerId.  It will make finding and storing the data that much easier.

Here's how I make the data structure

```
from __future__ import print_function #I'm using 3.x style print
import pandas as pd

#better to read these from a file
contracts = pd.DataFrame([
        ['IBM','SMART','USD'],
        ['AAPL','SMART','USD'],
        ['GOOG','SMART','USD'],
        ['ES','GLOBEX','USD','201506','50'],
        ['CL','NYMEX','USD','201506','1000']
])

# make decent column names
contracts.columns = ['sym','exch','curr','expiry','mult']

#add these specific column names to match the name returned by TickType.getField()
contracts['bidPrice'] = 0
contracts['askPrice'] = 0
contracts['lastPrice'] = 0
```

Now to make the requests I just loop through the data frame.  In the callback I use the tickerId to find the row in the data frame.

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt
from time import sleep

def error_handler(msg):
    print (msg)

def my_callback_handler(msg):
    if msg.field in [tt.BID,tt.ASK,tt.LAST]:
        #now we can just store the response in the data frame
        contracts.loc[msg.tickerId,tt.getField(msg.field)] = msg.price
        if msg.field == tt.LAST:
            print(contracts.loc[msg.tickerId,'sym'],msg.price)

tws = ibConnection(clientId=1)
tws.register(my_callback_handler, message.tickPrice, message.tickSize)
tws.register(error_handler, 'Error')
tws.connect()

for index, row in contracts.iterrows():
    c = Contract()
    c.m_symbol = row['sym']
    c.m_exchange = row['exch']
    c.m_currency = row['curr']
    c.m_secType = 'STK' if row['expiry'] is None else 'FUT'
    c.m_expiry = row['expiry']
    c.m_multiplier = row['mult']
    # the tickerId is just the index in but for some reason it needs str()
    tws.reqMktData(str(index),c,"",False)
```

Now I have all my current data if I want to use it somehow.  Another option would be some structure to save it and make a graph.
[image]

Comment: This was immensely helpful!  I am very greatful for your generous help.

Comment: after adding the necessary columns to the data frame above that would correspond to each 5 minute interval of the trading day, how would i dump some calculated number such as number of ticks or sum of volume for 5 minutes into each sequential column as each 5 minute period elapsed?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You should ask a new question and tag it python.  I don't use python much and I'm not sure if you just want to print every 5 min, or save the data every 5 min.

Comment: @brian How would you do a similar thing with the Java API? I'm starting out with this (self-learning) and I'm totally lost. This is basically the same exact thing that I want to do but not using Python.

Comment: @jonnyd42 ask a new question with some sample code you've tried.  Don't include the impl of EWrapper as it's very long.  I've also not used the beta API (9.72 I think) so I can't help with that.

Comment: @brian I'm using API 9.71. Please see my post:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138288/ib-java-api-extracting-ticker-data-real-time-bars-for-multiple-contracts